# When closing a RabbitMQ connection, what units are the timeout int argument? Seconds?

Tags: .net, rabbitmq

In the part of my RabbitMQ code where I am closing my connection, I see that there's an overload that allows me to specify a timeout.  The timeout argument is an `int`.  What are the units of this argument?

I checked the .Net [documentation for the `IConnection.Close(int timeout)`](http://www.rabbitmq.com/releases/rabbitmq-dotnet-client/v3.1.5/rabbitmq-dotnet-client-3.1.5-client-htmldoc/html/type-RabbitMQ.Client.IConnection.html#method-M%3aRabbitMQ.Client.IConnection.Close%28System.Int32%29) but they don't mention units.  If I set the timeout to 1000, is that 1000 seconds? 1000 milleseconds?  What?  Also, how do I check this?  I don't know how make this code timeout.

*If any RabbitMQ people are reading this, why not make the timeout argument a `TimeSpan`?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's Milliseconds.

In the RabbitMQ source code for .Net you can see where this is used in ConnectionBase.cs like so:

```
m_appContinuation.WaitOne(BlockingCell.validatedTimeout(timeout),true)
```

The method signature for WaitOne can be found on MSDN [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kzy257t0.aspx) and this states the timeout as milliseconds.

I agree though, that this should be clearer.